# Оператор присваивания += для списков (добавление по месту)

Tags: python

Как работает оператор `+=` и аналогичные ему? То есть, понятно, что `x+=y` - это аналог `x = x + y`.

Но я столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
x = []
y = (1,2,3)
x = x + y
```

В этом случае будет ошибка:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Но если написать

```
x += y
```

То значение `x` будет выводиться как

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Можно почитать [здесь](http://bugs.python.org/issue575536). Если коротко: `a = a + b` не равно `a += b`. Последнее - это вроде `a.extend(b)`

Comment: Будет много весёлого дебага, если где-то в коде ещё окажется `z = x`...

Comment: @ВОРОН, возможно, вам стоит оформить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Answer (score 8):

`x += y` для списков эквивалентен `x.extend(y)` и допускает произвольный *итерируемый* объект на месте `y`, например:

```
>>> import random
>>> L = [1]
>>> L += (i for i in range(10) if random.random() < .9)
>>> L
[1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Результат в данном случае может даже меняться от запуска к запуску.

Поэтому `x += y` работает, если `x` является списком даже если `y` является кортежем (кортеж является *итерируемым* объектом).

Если поменять местами `x`, `y`, то выражение перестанет работать: *неизменяемые* объекты, такие как кортежи не переопределяют `__iadd__` метод, реализующий `+=` оператор, и поэтому `tup += [1]` эквивалентно, `tup = tup + [1]` что ведёт к ошибке, показанной в вопросе.

Сложение списков и кортежей запрещено, так как не ясно какой результат должен быть (список или кортеж).

Подробности можно почитать [выполнив `help('+=')` в Питон-консоли или `pydoc "+="` из командной строки](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> An augmented assignment expression like "x += 1" can be rewritten as
>   "x = x + 1" to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In the
>   augmented version, "x" is only evaluated once. Also, when possible,
>   the actual operation is performed *in-place*, meaning that rather than
>   creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object
>   is modified instead.

То есть `x += 1` и `x = x + 1` похожи, но результаты могут отличаться как в данном случае.

Answer (score 3):

У изменяемых коллекций в Python метод += работает таким образом, что изменяет коллекцию на месте, в отличие от оператора +, который создаст новый объект.

Итак, код

```
x = []           # id(x) == 140412468236104
x += (1, 2, 3)   # id(x) == 140412468236104
```

примерно эквивалентен

```
x = []                # id(x) == 140412465906440
x.extend((1, 2, 3))   # id(x) == 140412465906440
```

При использовании оператора + создаётся новый объект:

```
x = []                # id(x) == 140412468319432
x = x + [1, 2, 3]     # id(x) == 140412511200328
```

Но при этом нужно помнить, что Python -- язык со строгой типизацией, поэтому не допустимо использовать оператор + на списке с кортежем. Именно поэтому возникает ошибка `TypeError`. Оператор + работает только с объектами одного типа (у стандартных объектов).

В своих объектах вы всегда можете перегрузить операторы, добавив то поведение, которое вам требуется.

Answer (score -1):

Как ведет себя `+=` определяется методом объекта `__iadd__(self, value, /)`.
Так как класс `list` реализован в Cи, то и динамическая типизация там не работает также как в питоне, а реализована логика в соответствии со стандартом.
То что не попадает под стандарт должно вызывать исключительное поведение. Тип содержимого перед обработкой проверяется и потому вызывается исключение.

Comment: Все объекты python (в том числе и встроенные, будь то list, tuple, str и т.д.) реализованы на Си в виде одной и той же структуры PyObject. С точки зрения языка Си нет разницы, объект какого класса передан в функцию, все равно это будет указатель на PyObject, так что исключение явно вызывается не из-за отсутствия динамической типизации в Си.

Comment: @insolor, не все, а основные. Указатель на структуру - согласен, но я немного не об этом. Нет единообразного и однозначного способа использовать этот метод для объектов разного типа. Пусть тип функция получает один и тот же, но содержимое этого типа проверяться должно. Исключение не вызывается при ошибке приведения - иначе был бы сегфолт программ на питоне.

Comment: @eri, вопрос-то в другом. А именно -- *почему += работает, а + нет?* Другими словами, почему в `+=` кортеж преобразуется в список, а в `+` нет? (А связи между реализацией  на Си и неработающей динамической типизацией нет никакой, как запрограммируете интерпретатор, так он и будет работать).

Comment: @avp я просто хотел сказать что __add__() и __iadd__() поразному описанны в объекте. даже если эти методы были бы написаны на другом языке, отличном от си. исправлю ответ.

Comment: @eri, видимо в ответе надо сосредоточиться на `что не попадает под стандарт должно вызывать исключительное поведение`. Т.е. неплохо было бы написать, что *конкретно* в стандарте (описании языка) приводит к такой реализации. И уж совсем хорошо было бы прояснить мотивы разработчика (Гвидо ван Россум).