# Неправильно подбираются множители

Tags: python, list

Почему, когда я ввожу простое и двузначное(или больше) число, например, 11, то вместо множителя `11`, он выводит `1, 1`.
Помогите исправить мне ошибку.

Заранее спасибо.

```
    nums = int(input("Сколько чисел: "))
    for number in range(1, nums+1):
        nums2 = int(input(f"Введите число {number}: "))
        numbers.append(nums2)
    numbers.sort()
    for num in numbers:
        num2 = int(num)
        while delitels != num:
            delimiy = 1
            while delimiy < num2:
                delimiy += 1
                if num2 % delimiy == 0:
                    break
            num2 /= delimiy
            delitels = delitels * delimiy
            deliteli2 += str(delimiy)
        alldels3.append(deliteli2)
        delitels = 1
        deliteli2 = []
        print(alldels3)
```

Comment: Исправьте для начала ошибку в коде, он нерабочий.

Comment: У меня есть продолжение, но я решил не писать весь код, чтобы не путать других, но запутал ещё больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в этой строке

```
deliteli2 += str(delimiy)
```

Если вы делаете `+=` для списка, то это даёт тот же результат, что и метод `extend`. Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446920/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83).

Таким образом ваша строка не добавляется к списку, как один элемент. Вместо этого интерпретатор посимвольно итерируется по строке, и добавляет к списку каждый символ как отдельный элемент.

Чтобы ваш код работал так, как вы хотите, замените эту строку на

```
deliteli2.append(delimiy)
```

PS: И в будущем когда приводите в вопросе код, убедитесь, что он вообще запускается. Иначе вероятность того, что вам помогут, сильно снижается.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял, что нужно заменить на append, но вы мне тоже помогли.